# Update nested documents inside array based on condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

i have the next document and i have to update `promotion` object according to `promotionId`
executing i can update, but this query erases the other products that have no the promotion in the condition:

if i use update many i get `Error: the update operation document must contain atomic operators`.
Please help me to get the error to update but keeping the products that does not have the promo i am updating. 
/* 1 */

```
db.fulFillmentCenter.update({},[
  {
    $addFields: {
      exclusiveProducts: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$exclusiveProducts",
          as: "product",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$product.promotion.promotionId",
              'promo1'
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {$set: { "exclusiveProducts.promotion.description": "multi 2"}}
```

/* 2 */

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "_class" : "com.walmart.labsmx.exclusiveproducts.model.FulFillmentCenter",
    "minDateDelivery" : 9,
    "maxDateDelivery" : 2,
    "deliveryCost" : 10.0,
    "origin" : "string",
    "active" : true,
    "exclusiveProducts" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : NumberLong(1585867035599),
            "upc" : "p1",
            "totalStock" : 10,
            "availableStock" : 10,
            "price" : 0.0,
            "origin" : "debe aparece",
            "startDate" : ISODate("2020-02-10T02:47:03.472Z"),
            "endDate" : ISODate("2020-04-10T02:47:03.472Z"),
            "active" : true,
            "promotion" : {
                "_id" : NumberLong(1585867035613),
                "promotionId" : "promo1",
                "description" : "string",
                "startDate" : ISODate("2020-04-30T17:49:27.205Z"),
                "endDate" : ISODate("2020-04-30T17:49:27.205Z"),
                "active" : true
            }
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : NumberLong(1585867035642),
            "upc" : "p2",
            "totalStock" : 10,
            "availableStock" : 10,
            "price" : 0.0,
            "origin" : "no debe aparece",
            "startDate" : ISODate("2020-02-10T02:47:03.472Z"),
            "endDate" : ISODate("2020-04-10T02:47:03.472Z"),
            "active" : false,
            "promotion" : {
                "_id" : NumberLong(1585867035654),
                "promotionId" : "promo1",
                "description" : "string",
                "startDate" : ISODate("2020-04-30T17:49:27.205Z"),
                "endDate" : ISODate("2020-04-30T17:49:27.205Z"),
                "active" : true
            }
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : NumberLong(1585867035607),
            "upc" : "p3",
            "totalStock" : 10,
            "availableStock" : 10,
            "price" : 0.0,
            "origin" : "no debe aparece",
            "startDate" : ISODate("2020-02-10T02:47:03.472Z"),
            "endDate" : ISODate("2020-03-10T02:47:03.472Z"),
            "active" : true,
            "promotion" : {
                "_id" : NumberLong(1585867035668),
                "promotionId" : "promo1",
                "description" : "string",
                "startDate" : ISODate("2020-04-30T17:49:27.205Z"),
                "endDate" : ISODate("2020-04-30T17:49:27.205Z"),
                "active" : true
            }
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : NumberLong(1585867035644),
            "upc" : "p4",
            "totalStock" : 10,
            "availableStock" : 10,
            "price" : 0.0,
            "origin" : "debe aparece",
            "startDate" : ISODate("2020-02-10T02:47:03.472Z"),
            "endDate" : ISODate("2020-05-10T02:47:03.472Z"),
            "active" : true,
            "promotion" : {
                "_id" : NumberLong(1585867035632),
                "promotionId" : "promo1",
                "description" : "string",
                "startDate" : ISODate("2020-04-30T17:49:27.205Z"),
                "endDate" : ISODate("2020-04-30T17:49:27.205Z"),
                "active" : true
            }
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : NumberLong(1585867035666),
            "upc" : "p5",
            "totalStock" : 10,
            "availableStock" : 10,
            "price" : 0.0,
            "origin" : "no debe aparece",
            "startDate" : ISODate("2020-05-10T02:47:03.472Z"),
            "endDate" : ISODate("2020-07-10T02:47:03.472Z"),
            "active" : true,
            "promotion" : {
                "_id" : NumberLong(1585867035591),
                "promotionId" : "promo1",
                "description" : "string",
                "startDate" : ISODate("2020-04-30T17:49:27.205Z"),
                "endDate" : ISODate("2020-04-30T17:49:27.205Z"),
                "active" : true
            }
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : NumberLong(1585867035669),
            "upc" : "p20",
            "totalStock" : 10,
            "availableStock" : 10,
            "price" : 0.0,
            "origin" : "no debe aparece",
            "startDate" : ISODate("2020-05-10T02:47:03.472Z"),
            "endDate" : ISODate("2020-07-10T02:47:03.472Z"),
            "active" : true,
            "promotion" : {
                "_id" : NumberLong(1585867035661),
                "promotionId" : "promo2",
                "description" : "string",
                "startDate" : ISODate("2020-04-30T17:49:27.205Z"),
                "endDate" : ISODate("2020-04-30T17:49:27.205Z"),
                "active" : true
            }
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : NumberLong(1585867035643),
            "upc" : "p21",
            "totalStock" : 10,
            "availableStock" : 10,
            "price" : 0.0,
            "origin" : "no debe aparece",
            "startDate" : ISODate("2020-05-10T02:47:03.472Z"),
            "endDate" : ISODate("2020-07-10T02:47:03.472Z"),
            "active" : true,
            "promotion" : {
                "_id" : NumberLong(1585867035612),
                "promotionId" : "promo3",
                "description" : "string",
                "startDate" : ISODate("2020-04-30T17:49:27.205Z"),
                "endDate" : ISODate("2020-04-30T17:49:27.205Z"),
                "active" : true
            }
        }
    ],
    "exclusiveStores" : [ 
        {
            "storeId" : 123,
            "origin" : "string"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please edit this question with 1) Input document, 2) Condition to check prior to update, 3) result document..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This update query updates all the nested documents `promotion` within the array `exclusiveProducts`. The value of `"promotion.description"` is modified with the new value `"multi 2"`, where the `"promotion.promotionId" = "promo1"`.

```
var new_desc = "multi 2";

db.collection.updateMany(
    { "exclusiveProducts.promotion.promotionId": "promo1" },
    { $set: { "exclusiveProducts.$[pr].promotion.description": new_desc } },
    { arrayFilters: [ { "pr.promotion.promotionId": "promo1" } ] }
)
```

Comment: thank you very much that is exactly what i was looking for, just 2 questions:
whats means $[pr] and arrayFilters are they functions in mongodb??

Comment: **(1)** The `[pr]` is the [filtered positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/index.html) used for updating array elements with condition specified on the element value. The name `pr` can be anything; it is user-defined. It represents the array element of the `exclusiveProducts` array which matches the condition `{ "exclusiveProducts.promotion.promotionId": "promo1" }`.

Comment: **(2)** The `arrayFilters` and the _filtered positional operator_ are used together; see the MongoDB documentation on [Specify arrayFilters for an Array Update Operations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#updatemany-arrayfilters).

Answer (score 2):

You should use `$elemMatch` to find the array index and `$` operator to update the data of that index accordingly

```
db.collection.updateOne(
    {"exclusiveProducts":{ "$elemMatch":{"promotion.promotionId":"promo1"} }},
    { $set: { "exclusiveProducts.$.promotion.description": "new description" } }
)
```