# How to modify array same values based on $

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data

I tried to modify array values with following :

```java
        final UpdateResult ur = operations.updateMulti(
                new Query().addCriteria(
                        Criteria.where("tags.applications").in(Collections.singletonList(4))),
                new Update().set(String.format("%s.$","tags.applications"), 8),
                "testMetaModel");
```

the problem is, if the array is like 
`tag: application: [1,2,3,4,4,5,6]`
If I use above "$" update, it could only update the first matched "4", but I want to update all "4" to "8", what should I do ? 
I use spring MongoTemplate.

Comment: Here are posts with answers related to your issue of updating an array element based on condition:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60701824/how-to-add-a-json-in-a-nested-array-of-a-mongodb-document-using-spring and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61002409/update-nested-documents-inside-array-based-on-condition/61004165#61004165

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the positional filters, refer [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#up._S_[%3Cidentifier%3E]).

shell query:

```
db.demo.update(
  {},
  {
    $set:{
      "a.$[element]":8
    }
  },
  {
    arrayFilters:[
      {
        "element":4
      }
    ]
  }
)
```

This will update all the matched elements in the provided array.

The above shell query is working fine. you can integrate it with your spring data. I tried to add that in springdata but fix it according to the shell query I provided if any issue is faced. :)

```
Update update=new Update().set("tags.applications.$[element]", 8).filterArray(Criteria.where("element").is(4)); 
final UpdateResult ur = operations.updateMulti(
        new Query(),
        update,
        "testMetaModel");
```

**Update**

Java driver query:

```
db.getCollection("demo").updateMany(
        new Document(),
        new Documen("$set", new Document("a.$[element]", 8)),
        new UpdateOptions().arrayFilters(
            Arrays.asList( 
            Document.parse("{'element': 4}")
            )
        )
);
```

Comment: It seems that I don't have the method: "update.filterArray(Criteria.where("element")." ? what could be done

Comment: seems like spring data does not have UpdateOptions. you can use java driver to update the document. please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/55503265/8383549

Comment: I have updated my answer with the java driver query. hope this will help you :)